# How can I remove not existing images in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, image, remove

How can I remove not existing images from magento. In the database have images but file is not exist. I want deleted this images from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create a test script mediaDelete.php at magento root and add below code and run that file from Command line**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$resourceConnection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);
$mediaConfig = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config::class);
$filesystem = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\Filesystem::class);
$mediaDir = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

$connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection('core_write');
$tableName = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery');
$result = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM .$tableName. where media_type = "image"');
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $imagePath = $mediaDir->getAbsolutePath($item['value']);

    if (!$mediaDir->isExist($imagePath)) {
        $sql = "Delete FROM " . $tableName . " Where value_id = " . $item['value_id'];
        $connection->query($sql);
    }
}
```

### Note, Code is not tested and the code  shared base on the idea.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it can remove all image because path should be ../pub/media/a/b/ab.jpeg but actually product image path is ../pub/media/catalog/product/a/b/ab.jpeg  so just change image path it work

Comment: OPPS, it was a mistake on `if (!$mediaDir->isExist($imagePath)) {` and it fixed now.

Comment: Had to adjust to $imagePath = $mediaDir->getAbsolutePath('catalog/product'.$item['value']); apart from that... perfect

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a direct solution for your store then you can use any of these opensource modules for your task,

https://github.com/sivaschenko/magento2-clean-media

https://cannycookie.github.io/Mage2UnusedImageRemover/

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner

Answer (score 1):

You can create a controller for deleting non-exist product images using following code, please have a look:

```
protected $_productCollection;
protected $_product;
protected $_driveFile;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $driveFile
) {
    $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
    $this->_product = $product;
    $this->_driveFile = $driveFile;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute() {
    // Get Product Ids list, you can change filter and condition accordingly
    $productIds = $this->_productCollection->create()->getAllIds();

    foreach ($productIds as $id) {
        // Load product by Id, because you can get media gallery images only using Product Model
        $productObj = $this->_product->load($id);

        // Get product media gallery images
        $images = $productObj->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItems();

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imagePath = $image->getPath();

            // Check if image exist, if not, then delete it
            if (!$this->_driverFile->isExists($imagePath))  {
                $this->_driverFile->deleteFile($imagePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this may helpful to you!